# Qt Creator: include directories

Tags: qt, function, user-interface, include

I'm trying to create a GUI and i'm having issues with some header files that the program needs and uses.

If i click on the function in the main.cpp it takes me to the header file. But for some reason when i compile the program I get "undefined reference to " the function in main.cpp.
Ive tried to add the path of the include folder where the header file in the .pro file but it didnt work.
It seems to me that Qt sees the function but somehow it doesnt compile.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: forgot to mention: I'm using Linux RedHat and Qt Creator 4.8

Comment: is this a problem with Qt header files or your header files?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ - To tell what exactly is missing you need to provide the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason the compiler did not see the library that the header file needed. it was specified in the makefile but it didnt work.

in the .pro file i added

LIBS += -lmylib

and that fixed the issue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the case of “undefined reference to” error,

In .pro file append or modify this line:

```
QT       += core gui sql printsupport network websockets
```

Maybe that's the same thing for you.

There is a similar description in the Qt document

```
Header: #include <QWidget>
qmake:   QT += widgets
```

You can find which header file corresponds to which module

Comment: for some reason the compiler did not see the library that the header file needed. it was specified in the makefile but it didnt work.

in the .pro file i added

 LIBS += -lmylib

and that fixed the issue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Including a header so the *compiler* can find the *declarations* of classes/methods/functions is one thing.

Adding source code or libs so that the *definition* of the declared facilities can be found by the *linker* is another.

> I get "undefined reference to " the function in main.cpp

This is a **linker error**. You either haven't added your own source files to the project, or any third-part libs you use. Open the context menu of your project in the left Creator pane and select "Add existing file..." for the first case or "Add library..." for the second.

And in the next step you should spend some time reading the [Creator manual](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/index.html) as well as some basics about C++ and compiling in general. All beginner questions like the above have already been answered multiple times, you just have to search for them.